# Texture in texture atlas is available in Xcode in a scene but not in running app

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, interface-builder, xcode8, sktextureatlas

Using Xcode 8, I have a texture atlas with a bunch of images in it in my project.  In the scene editor, I can select a sprite and in the Texture field for thats sprite I can click and get a list of all textures (images) in the project, INCLUDING those in the texture atlas.  I select a texture from the texture atlas.  When running the app I don't get the texture on the sprite.  I get a big red X.

I know I can programmatically get a texture from the atlas and assign it to the sprite.  I want to know why the Xcode (IB) assignment to the sprite works inside of Xcode (IB) but not in the running app.  I should be able to assign textures from texture atlases inside of Xcode to a sprite.

If I assign a texture from a normal graphics image not in the atlas it works.

Comment: It turns out that by removing the spaces in the image names it started to work.  I am testing more to figure out before I post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you select the Assets.xcassets file and see in the File Inspector (far right, first icon, looks like a paper page) if your target is checked in the Target Membership list? This is usually an excellent reason not to get any images from the asset catalog.

Comment: Thanks.  The assets are in a texture atlas, not the asset catalog.  And both the asset catalog and the texture atlas are in the target.  Thanks,

Comment: OK. Just out of curiosity - is there any benefit of using texture atlases outside the asset catalog?

Comment: I need to do the test but I don't think a texture group in the asset catalog is compiled as a texture atlas.  The docs give no indication at any rate that a texture group would be compiled as a texture atlas.  The docs on texture atlas only specify the directory.atlas way.